# The service is currently unavailable. This is most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firestore in a Flutter app using the following code, but I'm encountering an error as mentioned in the title.

```dart
  Future<dynamic> fetchFieldValue({
    required String collectionPath,
    required String documentPath,
    required String targetFieldKey,
  }) async {
    final documentSnapshot = await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection(collectionPath)
        .doc(documentPath)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));  // An error is thrown here.
    return documentSnapshot.get(targetFieldKey);
  }
```

I am executing the following configuration, but the error persists.

```dart
  void configureOfflinePersistence() {
    _firebaseFirestore.settings = const Settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
  }
```

By the way, removing the argument in `.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache))` and executing it as `.get()` does not throw an error.

How can this error be improved or resolved?